Why are there challenges for sparse vectors (in e.g., CSR format) compared to dense vectors?
I am currently looking at the big-ann competition tracks and noticed that a sparse track exists. This sparse track contains the MSMARCO dataset which contains a lot of sparse vectors. Moreover, these sparse vectors are ranked with the SPLADE model to only have vectors containing non-zero elements.
I am wondering, why is there a different track, when in the end the SPLADE sparse vectors are pretty much dense vectors. What are the specific challenges here compared to datasets containing dense vectors?
